# Output vowels in c

Tags: c, string

Can you help me? I need to output vowel from a string that I am reading from a file. Why does not my condititon fit for that?

```
if(mainArr[i]==vows[j])
 {
  res[l]=vows[j];
  l++;
 }
```

I read  my string successfully,but guess that need to use a special function from `#include <string.h>` for comparing.
Can you help to find another variant to compare letters?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fileIn;
    int i,j,l,k,z;
    char mainArr[40];
    char vows[]={'a','e','i','o','y','u','A','E','I','O','Y','U'};
    char res[30];
    if ((fileIn = fopen ("1.txt","r"))!=NULL)
    {

        fgets(mainArr,40-1,fileIn);
        puts(mainArr);



        for (i=0;i<strlen(mainArr);i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<strlen(vows);j++)
                {
                  if(mainArr[i]==vows[j])
                    {
                    res[l]=vows[j];
                    l++;
                    }
                }
        }

        for (k=0;k<l;k++)
        {
            printf("%c",res[k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `j<strlen(vows)`. `vows` is not a string so you cannot use `strlen` on it. Either use `sizeof(vows)` or ensure `vows` is NUL terminated.

Comment: You never initialized `l` to 0 so your code has undefined behaviour there too. Better to use `char *vows = "aeiouyAEIOUY";` with that null termination - also use pointers instead of indexing - more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

My errors are:

1. I can not use `strlen()` for vows because `vows` is not a string.
2. Didn't initialize `l`

   ```
   int main()
   {
       FILE *fileIn;
       FILE *fileOut;
       int i,j,l=0,k,z;
       char mainArr[40];
       char vows[]={'a','e','i','o','y','u','A','E','I','O','Y','U'};
       char res[30];
       if ((fileIn = fopen ("1.txt","r"))!=NULL)
       {

           fgets(mainArr,40-1,fileIn);
           puts(mainArr);



           for (i=0;i<strlen(mainArr);i++)
           {
               for(j=0;j<11;j++)
                   {
                     if(mainArr[i]==vows[j])
                       {
                       res[l]=vows[j];
                       l++;
                       }
                   }
           }

           for (k=0;k<l;k++)
           {
               fprintf(fileOut,"%c",res[k]);
           }
       }
       else 
       {
           printf("Error: can't open file (1)\n");
           exit(1);
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Thanks for helping so much!

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. Just a note on best practices. Using magic numbers like `j<11` and `40-1` is very bad practice. It is often unclear what these numbers represent and even worse, if the variable that they refer to changes then the magic number needs to change too (which is error prone). Instead use mechanisms like `sizeof` to get the numbers dynamically.